# Prometheus go client error context deadline exceeded

Tags: go, prometheus

I have a Prometheus server with a DB containing some metrics. I need a process that fetches these metrics from the DB and sends them to another server in a loop every minute. I wrote the following coding taking it from Prometheus examples:

```
client, err := api.NewClient(api.Config{Address: "http://localhost:9090",})
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

v1api := v1.NewAPI(client)
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

for { //main loop
    if result, warnings, err := v1api.Query(ctx, "patroni_patroni_info", time.Now().Add(-1 * time.Minute)); err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    } else {
        if len(warnings) > 0 {
            log.Warning(warnings)
        }
        if err = sendMetricToAnotherServer(result); err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }
    }
    log.Debugf("main sleeping %ds...", opts.ServersRefreshLoopSeconds)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(opts.ServersRefreshLoopSeconds))
}
```

Now the first send works fine but I got the following error starting from the second send.

```
2020/11/10 09:56:36 ERROR main: Post http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query: context deadline exceeded
```

I think the reason is that the deadline for the context passed to the Query API expired. The solution to solve the issue is to simply move the following two lines in the loop:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
```

I verified it worked and now it is able to send the metrics every minute but I am not sure this fix works properly in the long run. I fear that the cancel function should be managed in a different way to properly release resources and eventually it is not necessary to create a context at every loop but simply expand the deadline.

Does anyone know I can properly fix my code to avoid possible memory leak or other potential future issues?

Comment: Yes, I understand this as said it in my message. But I don't know how to properly manage the cancel operation. Moreover, call every time context.WithTimeout will create a new context of 10 secs of life. In a loop, this will create a lot of objects, is there a way to reuse the same context and simply expand the deadline of 1 minute? I see the API but even WithDeadline create a copy of the context.

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
```

This context is a total of 10 sec used by all requests; you should move this inside for loop so each request can have 10sec context.

Ideally, you will not want this defer to keep stacking; so you can either

1. Move it to another function (or create an inline function and call it) This makes sure defer function is called every time and is not stacked.
2. Call the cancel function at the end of the loop manually.